# WPF button style with icon throws System.Windows.Data Error only at runtime

Tags: wpf, button, styles

I created a style for buttons inside a toolbar which is a combination of a icon and text:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="BtStyle_ToolBar">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Button}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}, Path=Tag}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}, Path=Content}" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Using it:

```
<Button Name="Bt_Export" Content="{x:Static p:Resources.Export}" Command="{Binding Path=CmdExport}"
                Padding="5" Style="{StaticResource BtStyle_ToolBar}" Tag="Resources/export_excel_16x16.png"/>
```

The problem is that at runtime an exception is thrown to the immediate window:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 6 : 'ObjectSourceConverter' converter failed to convert value 'Resources/export_excel_16x16.png' (type 'String'); fallback value will be used, if available. BindingExpression:Path=Tag; DataItem='Button' (Name='Bt_Export'); target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource') IOException:'System.IO.IOException: Cannot locate resource 'themes/resources/export_excel_16x16.png'.
```

But at design time everything works fine...

How can I solve this issue?

**EDIT (Workaround)**

I removed the content property from the button declaration:

```
<Button Name="Bt_Export" Style="{StaticResource BtStyle_ToolBar}">
      <DockPanel>
           <Image Source="/Resources/export_excel_16x16.png"/>
           <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="center" Text="{x:Static p:Resources.Export}"></TextBlock>
       </DockPanel>
 </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Button Name="Bt_Import" Command="{Binding Path=CmdImport}" Style="{StaticResource BtStyle_ToolBar}">
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Static p:Resources.Import}"/>
    <Image Source="Resources/import_16x16.png"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Or just set it at the template level.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="BtStyle_ToolBar">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Button}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="Resources/import_16x16.png" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Awesome" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion and I got a "The property Content has been set more than once" error.

Comment: I set the content this way based on an example found in the internet. I don't know other way of doing it...

Comment: Ah right, ya should have noticed that, see edited example. However if they're two buttons that will always remain the same, I would set them as hard set values at the template level and just accomplish it by calling it as a staticresource to your button(s) as needed.

Comment: P.S. - Maybe it's just me, but why you're using all that relativesource ancestor source relationship stuff in your template, I don't quite understand. Maybe if you just make a quick sketch/picture of what you're after it would be easier to just give you a more legit template to work with in the first place?

Comment: I just upvoted your anwser but not yet what I was looking for, I'd like to know why the issue only happens at runtime...

Comment: All that relativesource ancestor source relationship stuff is just the way to inherit the properties I need from the actual button declaration.

Comment: Ya but from what I can tell it's not necessary and it brakes at runtime because you're confusing it by trying to pass your source string through your tag when it's then looking for it in an ancestor as themes/resources etc. You could just make two quick templates and change the picture/text for each and apply them to button controls as necessary, or omit the templates and hard set the values to the buttons without any bindings. Basically I think you copied a slop template from the internet. Make sense?

Comment: Your solution keeps throwing the "The property Content has been set more than once" error. I saw your answer edit, but what's the point of setting the image with a fixed string in a template level? Templates are supposed to be generic... Anyway, thanks for your efforts ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11385/discussion-between-eduardo-brites-and-chris-w)

Comment: Sorry amigo, you're getting that error because you're setting the content of the control more than once. It wasn't meant to be a copy/paste example but just to show concept. You're looking for a copy/paste answer to solve it, I was trying to learn you something. I suggest you look at a default wpf button template as an example to start from. And no, templates are not always meant to be generic. I might also suggest heading over to the Microsoft Expression site and watching some tutorial videos. Sorry I couldn't help with the time provided, best of luck! :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I know, I already answered back to you in the chat.

Comment: Sorry mate can't do the chat thing at work, if you'd like I can help more later.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, have you noticed that the image it is complaining about is export_excel_16x16.png but the XAML you posted is talking about import_16x16.png. Are you sure you aren't misinterpreting the cause of the error? i.e You have XAML elsewhere that is the issue. And Chris W. is correct also check the build action of the image.

Thanks

Comment: I have two buttons "Import" and "Export", the issue happens with both. I edited my answer though.